# Why is css formatting not working on a site after using virtual host?

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost

Good day,

I have setup my `http-vhosts.conf` as follows:

> Server name: aserv.domain.com
>   directory: /htdocs
>
> Server 2 name: bserv.domain.com
>   directory: /htdocs/bserv

So essentially server 2 can be accessed like: `aserv.domain.com/bserv`.

when going to `bserv.domain.com` the display is plain html without css formatting and images. Yet when i go to `aserv.domain.com/bserv`, the site displays with correct formatting, css and images. Furthermore functions such as logging in do not work when accesssing from `bserv.domain.com` are working from `aserv.domain.com/bserv`.

Sorry for being long winded, the problem persists even if I change the directory of server 2 to outside htdocs. eg. `/htdocs2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies for the vague question, I managed to solve this problem by changing the default directory in the `config.php` file.

I changed the relative path to the URL: `bserv.domain.com`

This would be useful to other implementing an open source web solution and that are missing formatting, css and images.